# Why doesn't copyTo copy a value to a different sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

Objective: Copy the contents of a cell on one sheet to another sheet.
Problem: Receive nothing instead of the cell contents.

Source code:

```
function DoesNotCopy() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() == 'GS') {
        var sheetST = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
        from = sheetST.getRange("B15:B15")
        var to = sheet.getRange(13, 2, 1, 1);
        from.copyTo(to);
    }
}
```

The contents of cell B15 is:
=round(sum(C15:F15))
The contents of cells C15 to F15 is a 1 in cell C15.
The attachment DoesNotCopy1 shows the spreadsheet from which
the copy is made.  The attachment DoesNotCopy2 show the spreadsheet to
which the copy is done.

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks,
[image: Spreadsheet prior to copyTo]
[image: Spreadsheet after copyTo]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem, if you still experience an issue - can you provide a test spreadsheet?

Comment: How can I attach a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange("C20").copyTo(dsh.getRange("C20"), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

[Range.copyTo(destination , options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))